# Issue with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll while converting application to 64 bit

Tags: .net, 32bit-64bit

We are working on converting a set .net applications to 64-bit from the original 32-bit. We have the code of the application. So we are recompiling the application with the any-CPU setting. We had so far issues with Oracle's data access components. For that, we set the reference as `copy local = false` and `specific version = false`. As these assemblies are installed in GAC, in the target machine, the reference is automatically set to the correct 64-bit version from the GAC (we install the assemblies in the GAC).

One of these application refer to the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll` and we are kind of stuck as we are not able to install these assemblies in the GAC and so the earlier technique is not working for us.

Now the problem is that I am not being able to run this application on a 64-bit OS. The dll reference is not working.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Please don't make us guess about the "issues".

Comment: @Hans: Do you have some solution for the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you run the office interop libraries as a prerequisite of your installer?

- [Designing and Creating Office
  Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3295w01c.aspx)
- [Office Solution
  Prerequisites for Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608617.aspx)

**UPDATED**

- [x86/x64 Runtimes](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=06c32242-2289-4471-93aa-ce96aa5cbc36&displaylang=en)

Comment: Does these dlls get installed in GAC?

Comment: I need the 32-bit and 64-bit version both, one for the compilation and the other for deployment. Where can I find them? Can you provide any link where I can download these from?

Comment: Here's the Office 2010 ones but they say they work with 2007, too. http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=06c32242-2289-4471-93aa-ce96aa5cbc36&displaylang=en