# InteropExcel.dll throwing error on server

Tags: asp.net, excel, interop

i am trying to create a workbook from the asp.net solution and save it at a specified folder but whilt creating the odject of workbook am getting this error

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005.

have tried setting permissions through dcomcnfg i.e. Interactive,launching and this user

I have deployed new build on IIS server... whenever i deploy new build i get this error

Answer (score 0):

If your server is 64-bit, that might be what's causing this issue. Take a look at this question on SO:

[Issue with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll while converting application to 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785315/issue-with-microsoft-office-interop-excel-dll-while-converting-application-to-64)